# Vue: Cannot find module (image) in the file

Tags: vue.js

I wrote a line which shows a picture like

[image]

And my asset folder is structured as

[image]

Yet this is throwing

[image: >Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/img/play.png'" found in ---> at resources/js/components/MusicPlayer.vue]

Solutions I've tried:

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Tried using
[image].
Still the same problem.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows `assets` under `public`, but your import URL uses the `@` prefix, which is a common alias for `<projectRoot>/src`.

You can move `public/assets` to `src/assets` so that the `@/assets` URL would be found:

```
public/assets --move--> src/assets
```

This solution has the advantage of minimizing the build output, only including files that are actually used in code. The included images also go through Webpack's processing, e.g., if you've configured image optimization.

Alternatively, you can keep `public/assets` and use a static asset URL, which is the base URL prefixed to the path under `public`. For the `play.img` and a base URL of `/` (the default), the static URL would be `/assets/img/play.img`:

```html
<img src="/assets/img/play.img">
```